# Analytic Function In The Complex Plane Which Always Gives Real Values

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $f$ be a non-constant, complex-valued function which is defined and analytic for all $z$ in the complex plane. Also, $f$ has the additional property that it is always real. To me, such a function seems bizarre and unlikely. Does such a function exist?

Comment: You might want to add the word _nonconstant_ somewhere...

Comment: Thank you Asal Beag Dubh. I forgot to dismiss the trivial solution.

Comment: You can use the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) to prove fairly easily that, if $f$ is defined and analytic for all $z$ in the complex plane, then $f'=0$ on the complex plane.  It follows that $f$ must be constant.

Comment: Yes, I see now that I could have easily solved this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using the Cauchy–Riemann equations, as mentioned in the comments, is probably the most elementary way. Here are two other possibilities.

If you can use Liouville's theorem, then $g(z)=\exp(i\,f(z))$ is an entire bounded function and hence constant. This means that $f$ takes values in a discrete set. Since $f$ is continuous, it must be constant.

If you can use the open mapping theorem, then the image of $f$ is not open and so $f$ must be constant.

Comment: Thank you. I already understand the solution to the problem.